# How to find the closest (x, y) position to (x,y) position in another list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two 2D lists with x and y coordinates and I want to go through list1, and for each point find the closest (x, y) coordinates in list2. They're of different lengths, and it's okay if I don't use all the points of list2 or even if I reuse points, as long as I go through all the points only once in list1. I need the shift itself as well as the location in the lists of both points. Here's what I have done to find the shift:

```
s_x = ([1.0,2.0,3.0])
s_y = ([1.5,2.5,3.5])
SDSS_x = ([3.0,4.0,5.0])
SDSS_y = ([3.5,4.5,5.5])

list1 = zip(s_x,s_y)
list2 = zip(SDSS_x,SDSS_y)

shift = []
place_in_array = []

for num,val in enumerate(list1):
    guess = 9999999999999.0
    place_guess = 0
    for index,line in enumerate(list2):
        new_guess = math.hypot(line[0] - val[0], line[1] - val[1])
        if new_guess < guess:
            guess = new_guess
            place_guess = index
    shift.append(guess)
    place_in_array.append(place_guess)

print shift
print place_in_array
```

but the output is this:

```
[2.8284271247461903, 1.4142135623730951, 0.0]
[0, 0, 0]
```

These are wrong, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: The output you have is correct at least according to my interpretation of the desired outcome. The 1st point in `list2`, (3.0,3.5) is the closest point to all 3 points in `list1`, so `place_in_array` is the zeroth index indication the 1st point in `list2` and the corresponding distances from each point in `list1` are the values in `shift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [specialized data structures for these geometric queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), with implementations that are debugged and efficient. Why not use them? [`sklearn.neighbors.BallTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) can do these types of queries, as well as [`sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree).

Comment: from what I can tell (though I'm not an expert) these functions aren't comparing two arrays, there's no place to input a second array, only to find "nearest neighbors" to a point in that array, whatever that means.

Comment: perhaps you can explain to me how I would use them, if it's possible, because I know they'd run faster and I'm trying to use this for a lot of data

Answer (score 2):

```
def lazy_dist(p0):
    return lambda p1:(p0[0] -p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2
closest_matches = {p0:min(list2,key=lazy_dist(p0)) for p0 in list1}
```

I think will do what you want (not very fast but it should work