# Give an (x,y) pair, how to choose which (x,y)_i pair is the closest - R

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, computational-geometry, tidyverse

I have a data frame (called coors) that contains a vector of x coordinates and a vector of y coordinates.

I have another data frame (called pickedPoint) that contains specified (x,y) pairs that are of interest.

The goal is to associate each `coors` point to its nearest pickedPoint. I want to use the `Euclidean norm (l-2)`. If at all possible please you tidyverse methods.

```
       Coor = data.frame(row = rep(1:96, each = 72),
                         col = rep(1:72, times = 96))

       PickedPoint = data.frame(ppRow = sample(96,10),
                                ppCol = sample(72,10))
```

There is another thread that is similar but is posted in python:

[How to find the closest (x, y) position to (x,y) position in another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190332/how-to-find-the-closest-x-y-position-to-x-y-position-in-another-list)

I have included a benchmark for the answers thus far:

```
microbenchmark(CPak(), latemail(),Jul(), times=10L)
Unit: milliseconds
expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
CPak()  37.83691   38.60585  43.66030   39.86094   44.9592     62.784 10
latemail() 4275.10 4536.783   4674.966   4712.938  4855.860   5045.069 10
Jul()   37.38809   39.87625   46.17202   44.90693   53.08938    57.33  10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often work on this kind of problem.

You're better off avoiding a tidyverse answer and using a vectorized approach. I like to use `outer` in this case, which is fast. I calculate distance as `Dist = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`.

```
myfun <- function() {
    Dx <- outer(Coor$row, PickedPoint$ppRow, "-")**2  # ** is same as ^
    Dy <- outer(Coor$col, PickedPoint$ppCol, "-")**2
    Dist <- sqrt(Dx+Dy)
    minDistind <- apply(Dist, 1, which.min)
    ans <- PickedPoint[minDistind,]
}
```

Output (head)

```
    ppRow ppCol
8      10    32
8.1    10    32
8.2    10    32
8.3    10    32
8.4    10    32
8.5    10    32
```

I compare to the other answers just for completeness

```
latemail <- function() {
    closest <- sapply( 1:nrow(Coor), function(x) which.min(sqrt(rowSums(sweep(PickedPoint, MARGIN=1, STATS=unlist(Coor[x,]))^2))) )
}
```

**Note** I added `sol <- PickedPoint[Coor$closest,]` to Jul's function because the original function only returned the indexes

```
Jul <- function() {
    require(sp)
    require(dplyr)
    Coor$closest <- spDists(as.matrix(Coor),as.matrix(PickedPoint)) %>% apply(1,which.min)
    sol <- PickedPoint[Coor$closest,]
}
```

**Benchmarking**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(myfun(), latemail(), times=10L)

       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq         max neval
    myfun()   50.34484   50.93591   53.75279   51.46284   55.46526    66.09656    10
 latemail() 9683.82227 9733.03489 9863.94716 9856.65472 9974.46137 10065.89549    10

microbenchmark(myfun(), Jul(), times=10L)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 myfun() 47.85368 50.13398 63.84994 50.82162 58.62493 167.69221    10
   Jul() 54.27473 54.38482 59.22976 58.56265 61.97588  69.11861    10
```

This illustrates why you should avoid tidyverse approach which is even slower than `sapply`

Note this answer compares all-to-all, which could be important if you're not using a simple toy example; with your toy example, you could use clever tricks to avoid all-to-all comparisons

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the `sp` package for this

```
library(sp)
library(dplyr)

Coor$closest <- spDists(as.matrix(Coor),as.matrix(PickedPoint)) %>% apply(1,which.min)
```

Comment: Nice to know this package exists